# Retrieve string from list if we know the index

Tags: java

Is there a way to retrieve a string from an ArrayList if we know the index of the string we want to retrieve? for example in this string:

```
String text2 = "if(AGE_Y>15){\r\n"
                + "x=PROPERTY_LENGTH;\r\n"
                + "}";
```

The list this string is added to would look like : `if, (, AGE_Y, >, 15, ), {, ...`

Now if we loop through the list and add each item to a StringBuilder and define the index for each item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   a=list.get(i);
   strBuilder.append(a); 
   index = strBuilder.length() - a.length();
}
```

We will know  exactly at what index we have the string "PROPERTY_LENGTH" for example.

My question is, how can we retrieve the string "x" from the List? I'm asking because at the line above "x"(or whatever that variable will be named) I want to insert something else in the StringBuilder. Normally we could do something like:

```
 String previous=list.get(indexOfPropertyLength-2);
 strBuilder.insert(index-previous.length-1,"string to insert");
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: any reason you want this to be handled through a list? you could do what you want using regex i guess (replace x=PROPERTY_LENGTH with the prefix and x=PROPERTY_LENGTH) ... you could also extract the value of PROPERTY_LENGTH is thats only a placeholder, if you need.

Comment: @aishwarya: I went with a list because what you see there as AGE_Y and PROPERTY_LENGTH are only two of about 1000+ possible (i call them references) to be used in such conditions and i didn't think regex would be suited for that (might be wrong though).

Comment: So is it an ArrayList or a StringBuilder?

Comment: @DanielV, sure. I would probably still suggest going with a regex (and use a logical `or` operation i.e. `|` to concat the references and build a regex). i personally find playing with indexes tricky when manipulating strings, so try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can rewrite your list iteration to work more efficiently:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    a=list.get(i);
    index = strBuilder.length(); // (you don't have to calculate an index)
    strBuilder.append(a); 
}
```

To address the title of your question, if you want to simply find a String in a List given an index, you can of course use `myList.get(myIntIndex);`. However, it seems that you're asking how to find an index given a String: `myList.indexOf(myString)` or something of that nature. If you could be a bit clearer, we might be of more help. Are you writing a hybrid assembler or compiler?

Comment: It's kind of a compiler. Saying "kind of" because it's nowhere near as complex but the basic idea is about the same. Thank you for the suggestion to rewrite that loop. About the "myList.get(myIntIndex)",the way i have retrieved the index makes it impossible to do that because after a certain point the value of index will always be larger than the size() of the list

Comment: Assemblers are tricky to write (compilers more so), but they employ similar strategies to organize their input. I would encourage you to try using a "lookup table" such as a Hashtable in Java which you can use to store the names and locations of any constants or variables (such as PROPERTY_LENGTH, etc). and easily reference them from that table when needed. It might not be a good idea to modify your input code as you process it, as it can interfere with references in the table and other such headaches.

Comment: If you're interested in learning more about common compiler and assembler design strategies, you should definitely check out "System Software: An Introduction to Systems Programming" by Leland Beck if you can, found [here](http://www.amazon.com/System-Software-Introduction-Systems-Programming/dp/0201423006).

Comment: Thank you, I will most likely get that :)

Comment: Regarding your index value becoming larger than the size of your list, storing variables in a lookup table instead of modifying the input code when variables are found prevents your indexes from jumbling around. If you want to keep things simple, make your compiler a "multi-pass compiler" in which it scans your entire input code multiple times. The first pass might gather variable names and locations in a lookup table. The second pass might replace variables in the input code with their equivalent values, etc.

Comment: Thank you , I will try to read up on your suggestion a bit so i can get a better idea of how and if i can implement it in my application.